# Did ZXING compatible with Automatic Reference Counting

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, zxing

I had implement the project that have to use QR Reader via Zxing Project.
and now I'm not sure about how compatible with ARC mode in Xcode4.2 , if I need to use Zxing Widget under ARC Mode.

Do I need to manually config compiler or project setting?
or any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  Just turn on ARC within your project and see what happens.

Each library that you include is supposed to do it's own memory management (ARC or not).